# Unzipping zipped dstream packages

Tags: solaris, sun, sunos, dstream

How to unzip the `.dstream.Z` package in Sun Solaris. I tried all the methods as under

*gunzip*

```
 # gunzip pkg@1821417@27528.dstream.Z

gzip: pkg@1821417@27528.dstream.Z: not in gzip format
```

*unzip*

```
# unzip pkg@1821417@27528.dstream.Z
Archive:  pkg@1821417@27528.dstream.Z
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of pkg@1821417@27528.dstream.Z or
       pkg@27528.dstream.Z.zip, and cannot find pkg@1821417@27528.dstream.Z.ZIP, period.
```

*jar*

```
 jar xf pkg@1821417@27528.dstream.Z
bash: jar: command not found
```

*cpio*

```
# cpio -idvu pkg@1821417@27528.dstream.Z
```

Here I had to press `Ctrl+C` as nothing print out.

Furthermore, I checked with *file* command:

```
# file pkg@1821417@27528.dstream.Z
pkg@1821417@27528.dstream.Z:   html document
```

Comment: Have you looked at the file to confirm it actually is a valid download and not an HTML error page telling you that your download failed?   If it was truly a valid *.Z file, gunzip should handle it.

Answer (score 1):

You should `uncompress` for such file with `.Z` suffix. It is an ancient tool these days, but it still works of course.

Something like this:

`uncompress pkg@1821417@27528.dstream.Z`